# Difference between committed instructions and committed ops

Tags: gem5

In stats.txt file i find that difference between commited instructions and Ops

> system.cpu_cluster.cpus.committedInsts           5028                       # Number of instructions committed
> system.cpu_cluster.cpus.committedOps          5834              # Number of ops commited

Can someone describe their difference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"committedInsts" is the architectural number of assembly instructions executed.

"commmittedOps" is the number of micro-operations. Each instruction can expand to multiple microoperations, so this number is always greater or equal than committedInsts.

See also: [Difference between an instruction and a micro-op](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33026830/difference-between-an-instruction-and-a-micro-op)

Comment: Thank you for the help. By the way i am reading your gem5 segments in linux kernel module cheat . They re very helpful!